# How to get Crystal Report all queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, crystal-reports, multi-database

There were 24 database in my project. One database has been seperated to 3 another databases. And now, I have to change all queries of Crystal Report.

How can I batch update all queries via C#? Is it possible?
or
How can I find out the questions that need to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

**private string getSQL(InfoObject iObject, EnterpriseSession eSession)
        {**
            CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument boReportDocument = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
            CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ISCDReportClientDocument boReportClientDocument;
            CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.DataDefController boDataDefController;
            CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.Database boDatabase;
            CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.CommandTable boCommandTable;

```
        // Load the report using the CR .NET SDK and get a handle on the ReportClientDocument
        boReportDocument.Load(iObject,eSession);
        boReportClientDocument = boReportDocument.ReportClientDocument;

        // Use the DataDefController to access the database and the command table.
        // Then display the current command table SQL in the textbox.
        boDataDefController = boReportClientDocument.DataDefController;
        boDatabase = boDataDefController.Database;

        string sql;
        sql = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < boDatabase.Tables.Count; i++)
        {
            CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.ISCRTable tableObject = boDatabase.Tables[i];

            if (tableObject.ClassName == "CrystalReports.Table")
            {
                sql = sql + "Table " + i + ": " + tableObject.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                boCommandTable = (CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.CommandTable)boDatabase.Tables[i];
                sql = sql + "Query " + i + ": " + boCommandTable.CommandText;
            }
            sql += Environment.NewLine;

        }

        foreach (string subName in boReportClientDocument.SubreportController.GetSubreportNames())
        {
            CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.SubreportClientDocument subRCD = boReportClientDocument.SubreportController.GetSubreport(subName);

            for (int i = 0; i < boDatabase.Tables.Count; i++)
            {
                CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.ISCRTable tableObject = boDatabase.Tables[i];

                if (tableObject.ClassName == "CrystalReports.Table")
                {
                    sql = sql + "Table " + i + ": " + tableObject.Name;
                }
                else
                {
                    boCommandTable = (CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.CommandTable)subRCD.DatabaseController.Database.Tables[i];
                    sql = sql + "Subreport " + subName + " - Query " + i + ": " + boCommandTable.CommandText;
                }
                sql += Environment.NewLine;
            }

        }


        // Clean up
        return sql;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*Doesn't this require the developer to have a licensed RAS SDK?*

Anyway this works AFAICT with my CR Developer license, so good to go.
I did modify it a bit to use a StringBuilder and so on as shown below... 
also

- uses log4net to dump the queries...
- shows where the RPT was loaded
  from (rptSourceName)
- Presents data from the RPT SummaryInfo object

  ```
    private void DumpQueries(CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument doc, string rptSourceName)
  {
      try
      {
          //CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument boReportDocument = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();

          CommandTable boCommandTable;
          var boReportClientDocument = doc.ReportClientDocument;
          var boDataDefController = boReportClientDocument.DataDefController;
          var boDatabase = boDataDefController.Database;

          var reportSummary = doc.SummaryInfo;
          var reportName = doc.Name ?? doc.FileName;

          //return; // disabled for now.

          //foreach (dynamic table in doc.ReportClientDocument.DatabaseController.Database.Tables)
          //{
          //    if (table.ClassName == "CrystalReports.CommandTable")
          //    {
          //        string commandSql = table.CommandText;

          //        Log?.DebugFormat(@"Report object: {0} - SQL: {1}", doc.Name, commandSql);
          //    }
          //}

          // revised based on  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43208449/how-to-get-crystal-report-all-queries/57822774#57822774



          var sb = new StringBuilder();
          sb.AppendLine();
          sb.AppendLine("---------- Summary -----------");
          sb.AppendLine($@"Report source: {rptSourceName}");
          sb.AppendLine($"Title: {reportSummary.ReportTitle}");
          sb.AppendLine($"Subject: {reportSummary.ReportSubject}");
          sb.AppendLine($"Comments: {reportSummary.ReportComments}");
          sb.AppendLine($"Author: {reportSummary.ReportAuthor}");
          sb.AppendLine($"Keywords: {reportSummary.KeywordsInReport}");
          sb.AppendLine($"Last Saved By: {reportSummary.LastSavedBy}");
          sb.AppendLine($"Revision #: {reportSummary.RevisionNumber}");
          sb.AppendLine("------------------------------");



          for (var i = 0; i < boDatabase.Tables.Count; i++)
          {
              ISCRTable tableObject = boDatabase.Tables[i];

              if (tableObject.ClassName == "CrystalReports.Table")
              {
                  sb.AppendLine(@"Table " + i + ": " + tableObject.Name);

              }
              else
              {
                  boCommandTable = (CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.CommandTable)boDatabase.Tables[i];
                  sb.AppendLine(@"Query " + i + ": " + boCommandTable.CommandText);
              }


          }

          sb.AppendLine("------------------------------");
          sb.AppendLine("");

          sb.AppendLine("--------- Subreports ---------");

          foreach (string subName in boReportClientDocument.SubreportController.GetSubreportNames())
          {



              SubreportClientDocument subRcd = boReportClientDocument.SubreportController.GetSubreport(subName);
              sb.AppendLine($@"Subreport object: {subRcd.Name}");
              sb.AppendLine("------------------------------");
              for (var i = 0; i < boDatabase.Tables.Count; i++)
              {
                  CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.ISCRTable tableObject = boDatabase.Tables[i];

                  if (tableObject.ClassName == "CrystalReports.Table")
                  {
                      sb.AppendLine(@"Table " + i + ": " + tableObject.Name);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      boCommandTable = (CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.CommandTable)subRcd.DatabaseController.Database.Tables[i];
                      sb.AppendLine(@"Query " + i + ": " + boCommandTable.CommandText);
                  }
                  //sql += Environment.NewLine;
              }


          }

          Log?.Debug($@"Report contents: {  sb.ToString()}");

      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          Log?.Error(ex);
          throw;
      }
  }
  ```

Generates:

```
    Report contents: 
---------- Summary -----------
Report source: zzzzzzzzz
Title: zzzzzzzz
Subject: zzzzzzzzz
Comments: zzzzzzzzz
Author: XXXXXXX
Keywords: XXXXXXX
Last Saved By:XXXXXXX
Revision #: 411
------------------------------
Query 0: SELECT B1.Brkey,I1.inspkey,
   B1.Strucname,
   P2.Pon_Session_Batch_Key,
   B1.Bridge_Id,
   B1.Struct_Num,
...
...
...
```